# Return a string value without quote marks in Next.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

> The problem as solved using .send instead .json, thank you

I have an API in next.js, but i need a string response without Quote Marks, actually my response in browser include "value", I want only value.

my current endpoint:

```
export default async function handler(
     req: NextApiRequest,
     res: NextApiResponse
     ){
      const response = 'value';

      res.status(200).json(response);
}
```

response on browser:
`"value"`
I expected:
`value`

I tried convert the value to json, but don't have success, return an error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0.

did not work the return I expected

Answer (score 0):

The browser will show the quote marks for a string in console log statements, inspected in your browser, but rendered in HTML the quote marks will not be present.  When strings are represented in JSON, they will always contain quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the quote marks, your response should be in JSON format:

```json
{"key": "value"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a response in a string like this "value" just use

```
JSON.parse(response)
```

To convert `"value"` to `value`